# Linking Two Foreign Keys to one Primary Key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, a Photographer and an Influences table. In the Influences table, a Photographer is able to influence another Photographer.

Relational Schema:

[image]

Here is my Diagram in SQL:

[image]

Instance Example:

[image]

My issue is when I try to delete Photographer Tom, since he influences Jason (as shown in Influences table), I get a error stating:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Influences_Photographer1". The conflict occurred in database "jma59", table "dbo.Influences"

If Tom was in the column EPName of the Influences table, I have no issue deleting it. I know that this is a foreign key issue but I am not sure how to handle this situation. I created two separate foreign keys that reference to the Photographer primary key. But the problem is that I cannot make it so that both foreign keys cascade on update and delete.

First foreign key is EPName and EPBDate referencing to PName and PBDate of Photographer

Second foreign key is RPName and RPBDate referning to PName and PBDate of Photographer as well.

The error is:

> Unable to create relationship 'FK_Influences_Photographer1'. Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Influences_Photographer1' on table 'Influences' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If two photographers influence each other, I don't understand why you would want to be able to delete one of them.  You need to delete the influence relationship first.

Comment: Say for instance I remove Tom from the Photographer table, it should remove the tuple shown above in the Influences table. Likewise if I delete Jason in the Photographer table it should remove that same tuple. I am not sure how to do this since it doesn't let me cascade from two different paths on the same attributes (PName,PBDate) of Photographer.

Comment: for `FK_Influences_Photographer1` make sure ON DELETE/UPDATE is set to NO Action, then set Enforce Foreign Key Constraint to `NO` or set it by code `ALTER TABLE Influences NOCHECK CONSTRAINT FK_Influences_Photographer1` this should make you able to delete Tom while keeping both foreign keys.

Comment: This will not solve the issue. This will make it so that when I delete Tom from the Photographer table the tuple in the Influences table will still be there. It is supposed to be removed since Tom is referenced in the RPName attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using a Trigger rather than a cascading delete to enforce referential integrity: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/321843/error-message-1785-occurs-when-you-create-a-foreign-key-constraint-tha